# Inheritance of VotingClassifier in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to modify the sklearn `VotingClassifier` to be used in a `RandomSearchCV`.
The idea being that for a larger number of classifiers the possible weight combinations explodes and is better represented by individual weight choices rather than many different tuples. Also this enables a change to a smarter hyperparameter tuning method as there is information in the change of weight.

So how do I correctly subclass the `VotingClassifier` Class as the below code results in either None being passed to the weights or the default being used and the search complaining about weights not being controlled by parameters (which they are).

```
class VotingClassifier2(VotingClassifier):
    def __init__(self, estimators, w1, w2, voting='soft', weights=None, n_jobs=None, flatten_transform=True):
        super().__init__(estimators, voting, weights, n_jobs, flatten_transform)
        if w1:
            tot=w1+w2 
        else:
            breakpoint()
        self.weights = (w1/tot, w2/tot)


pipe = Pipeline(
    [
        [
            "vc",
            VotingClassifier2(
                estimators=[
                    ("xgb", XGBClassifier()),
                    ('lr', LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True, max_iter=300, solver='lbfgs'))

                ],
                voting="soft",
                weights=None,
                w1=1,
                w2=0

            ),
        ]
    ]
)


opt = RandomizedSearchCV(
    pipe,
    { 
        "vc__w1": uniform(0.1, 1),   
        "vc__w2": uniform(0.1, 1)
    },
    n_iter=5,
    cv=5,
    n_jobs=25,
    return_train_score=False,
    error_score='raise' 
)
```

When called initially w1 and w2 are None but weights has already been calculated as desired from the inputs. Then the search runs and fails to set them.

```
RuntimeError: Cannot clone object VotingClassifier2(estimators=[('xgb', XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
       colsample_bynode=1, colsample_bytree=1, gamma=0, learning_rate=0.1,
       max_delta_step=0, max_depth=3, min_child_weight=1, missing=None,
       n_estimators=100, n_jobs=1, nthread=None,
       objectiv...alty='l2', random_state=None, solver='warn',
          tol=0.0001, verbose=0, warm_start=False))]))],
         flatten_transform=True, n_jobs=None, voting='soft', w1=None,
         w2=None, weights=(1.0, 0.0)), as the constructor either does not set or modifies parameter weights
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RandomizedSearchCV` changes estimators' parameters via attributes, so if you want to modify `weights` attribute along with `w1` and `w2` you can wrap them with `property` decorator. Another option is to wrap `weights` directly e.g.:

```
import scipy as sp
from dask_ml.xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV


class VotingClassifier2(VotingClassifier):
    @property
    def weights(self):
        return self._weights

    @weights.setter
    def weights(self, value): 
        if isinstance(value, float):
            value = [value, 1-value]
        self._weights = value


# setup a client based on your environment 
client = ...

pipe = Pipeline(
    [
        [
            "vc",
            VotingClassifier2(
                estimators=[
                    ("xgb", XGBClassifier(sheduler=client)),
                    ('lr', LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True, max_iter=300, solver='lbfgs'))

                ],
                voting="soft",
                weights=[.5, .5],
            ),
        ]
    ]
)


opt = RandomizedSearchCV(
    pipe,
    { 
        "vc__weights": sp.stats.uniform(0.1, 1),   
    },
    n_iter=5,
    cv=5,
    n_jobs=25,
    return_train_score=False,
    error_score='raise' 
)
```

EDIT:
If you really need to use `w1` and `w2` you should bound them to `weights` and drop `weights` from `__init__` method arguments:

```py
class VotingClassifier2(VotingClassifier):
    def __init__(self, estimators, w1, w2, voting='soft', n_jobs=None, flatten_transform=True):
        super().__init__(estimators, voting, [w1, w2], n_jobs, flatten_transform)
        self.w1 = w1
        self.w2 = w2

    @property
    def w1(self):
        return self.weights[0]

    @w1.setter
    def w1(self, value): 
        if value is not None:
            self.weights[0] = value

    @property
    def w2(self):
        return self.weights[1]

    @w2.setter
    def w2(self, value): 
        if value is not None:
            self.weights[1] = value
```

Comment: That is great, but I'm not really able to make it into using new arguments such as `w1`, `w2` etc. And that is really the crux of the matter.

Comment: like I said if you want to add `w1` and `w2` attributes you have to make sure that they are bound to `weights`.  see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

there might be a simpler and more scalable solution to your questions. Instead of trying to search for the best params combination using grid search, you can try to use stacking method. For stacking, the base learners are your xgb and lr, and you can choose linear regression as your meta learner. And then you just let linear regression to figure out the coefficients (weights) for each of the base learners.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but no, gridsearch is not more scalable. For more complex fits a meta search like BaysioanSearchCV should be used, which has the same structure as randommsearch.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to create the weights tuple before-hand using `ParameterSampler` of `RandomizedSearchCV` instead of incorporating this aspect into the class.

Then use can use the `weights` output from `ParameterSampler` into `GridSearchCV`.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterSampler
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier

from scipy.stats.distributions import uniform
params = {'w1': uniform(),  'w2': uniform()}
params_order = list(params)

param_list = list(ParameterSampler( params, n_iter=2, random_state=1))

weights = []
for d in param_list:
    total = sum(d.values())
    weights.append(tuple(d[k]/total for k in params_order))

weights
#[(0.36666223123984704, 0.633337768760153),
# (0.00037816489242002753, 0.99962183510758)]

pipe = Pipeline([["vc", VotingClassifier(estimators=[("xgb", XGBClassifier()),
                                                       ('lr', LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True,
                                                                                 max_iter=3,
                                                                                 solver='lbfgs'))],
                                          voting="soft",
                                          weights=None)]])


opt = GridSearchCV(
    pipe,
    { 
        "vc__weights": weights,   
    },
    cv=5,
    n_jobs=25,
    return_train_score=False,
    error_score='raise' 
)

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
X,y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)  
opt.fit(X,y)
```

Remember doing it this way does not reduce the search space of weights, we are just normalizing the weights. Hence the computation complexity is still the same.

I would recommend using the Bayesian optimization instead of `GridSearchCV` / `RandomSearchCV`.

Try using [`BayesSearchCV`](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/#skopt.BayesSearchCV) or [`Hyperopt`](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt-sklearn)

## Update:

As you are trying to use the bayesian optimization, we can move away from `GridSearchCV`.

If you are fine with using hyperopt, the solution very simple for handling this individual weights tuning.

Take a look at this following example:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
X,y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)  

from hyperopt import fmin, tpe, hp, STATUS_OK
from sklearn.base import clone
import numpy as np
import warnings
from sklearn.utils.testing import ignore_warnings
from sklearn.exceptions import ConvergenceWarning

space ={'w1': hp.uniform('w1', 0.1, 1),
        'w2': hp.uniform('w2', 0.1, 1),}

pipe = Pipeline([["vc", 
                  VotingClassifier(estimators=[("xgb", XGBClassifier()),
                                               ('lr', LogisticRegression(
                                                   multi_class='auto',
                                                   fit_intercept=True,
                                                   max_iter=10,
                                                   solver='lbfgs'))],
                                      voting="soft",
                                      weights=None)]])

@ignore_warnings(category=ConvergenceWarning)
def objective(weights):

    model = clone(pipe)
    model.set_params(vc__weights=(weights['w1'], weights['w2']))
    model.fit(X,y)
    cv_scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=5)

    # negate the scores, as loss is being minimized
    return  {'loss': -np.mean(cv_scores), 'status': STATUS_OK }

best = fmin(objective,
    space=space,
    algo=tpe.suggest,
    max_evals=50)

print (best)

# best loss: -0.9866666666666667
# {'w1': 0.12142275807258746, 'w2': 0.8458018232585609}
```

Comment: Thanks for your hints. The reason I need the sub-classing is exactly to use BaysianSearchCV which has a chance of learning something about the underlying effects of the individual weights.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately, I need to stick to the sklearn API style, so its BaysianSearchCV rather than hyperopt (BaysianSearchCV only outperforms RandomSearchCV for complicated models in a given time frame).